# Need your help on Full Triple DES MAC in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, tripledes

My work needs the full triple DES MAC function in .NET (as as defined in [ISO 9797-1] as MAC Algorithm 1 with output transformation 1, without truncation, and with triple DES taking the place of the block cipher)

My problem is that I don't know how to implement this algorithm in C#.NET

Is there any suggestion (or code snippet) that would helps me implementing it (.NET Class and method)

Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Hai-Binh LE

Answer (score 0):

The .Net Library already contains an implementation of the TripleDES Message Authenticator Code algorithm.

You can find the documentation and example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.mactripledes%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

You didn't mention which version of the .net framework you were using, incidentally, so I've assumed 3.5 here.

Comment: Hi pobk,

thank you for your reply. I'm not expert in crypto and I know that there's 6 variants as in ISO9797-1. I'm wondering if I can use this class to implement the Algorithm 1 in the ISO9797-1 CBC-MAC?

By the way, I use .NET 3.5 :-)

Comment: Is there any library in .Net helps generating MAC using retail MAC (Algo3)?